# Why does omitting trailing slash cause 404?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I am trying to deny access to PHP from all subfolders recursively by setting `SetHandler default-handler` which works, but I also want to allow PHP to be executed on the root domain /index.php *only*.

```
<FilesMatch "^index\.php$"> 
     <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/[^/]+\.(php)$#">
         SetHandler "proxy:unix:/usr/local/php81/sockets/mirrors.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

This produces the correct behaviour, but all the subfolders require '/' in the URL. This must be because the preg search is matching `/path/to/folder/index.php` so I tried `^/[\w\d]+\.(php)$` (plus others) also this works but still, the trailing slash is needed.

Thanks in advance. If anybody can offer a more elegant way of doing this that would work also.

**Edit**

```
<Files ?*>
    SetHandler default-handler
</Files>
```

The above is what causes the 404 on folders with no trailing slash. It matches all files with 1 or more letters. So all files.

If that can be removed, sure, that's a valid answer.

Here is the full code, which works, except for the folders with no trailing slash.

```
<Files ?*>
    SetHandler default-handler
</Files>
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/[^/]+(\.php)$#">
     SetHandler "proxy:unix:/usr/local/php81/sockets/mirrors.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</If>
```

Comment: So `/index.php` is the only thing that should be parsed as PHP, anything else named `.php` in the root folder, or anything `.php` (including `index.php`) in any subfolder, should not? Would this not be easier then if you left out the FilesMatch directive completely, and just checked that the request URI was _not_ `/index.php`?

Comment: @CBroe has got a valid point.

Comment: Correct, everything else should *not* be parsed. I'll update the question with more.